# Can't execute java program on CentOS 7

Tags: java, centos, jira, centos7

Follow this guide to test JIRA performance:

https://github.com/atlassian/jira-performance-tests/blob/master/docs/tests/ON_PREMISE.md

Installed JAVA by:

```
$ sudo yum install java-11-openjdk-devel
```

Use this way got installed JAVA path:

```
$ update-alternatives --config java
java-11-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.5.10-0.el7_7.x86_64/bin/java)
```

Set `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.5.10-0.el7_7.x86_64/bin/java` to ~/.bash_profile as env variable:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.5.10-0.el7_7.x86_64/bin/java
```

Source file:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Check JAVA_HOME:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.5.10-0.el7_7.x86_64/bin/java
```

From JIRA test path run test command:

```
$ cd jira-performance-tests/examples/btf-test
$ ./mvnw verify
```

Got error:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.5.10-0.el7_7.x86_64/bin/java/bin/java
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually `JAVA_HOME` is given without `/bin/java`.
I suggest changing the `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.5.10-0.el7_7.x86_64`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do something like this to export the Java_Home

> export
>   JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.5.10-0.el7_7.x86_64/"
>   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Answer (score 0):

add JAVA_HOME to the classpath

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You should setup `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.5.10-0.el7_7.x86_64/bin/java/bin
```

To set JAVA_HOME, do one of the following:

*For Korn and bash shells, run the following commands:*

```
export JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

*For the bourne shell, run the following commands:*

```
JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir

export JAVA_HOME

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export PATH
```

*For the C shell, run the following commands:*

```
setenv JAVA_HOME jdk-install-dir

setenv PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

For more info have a look at [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html)